# Elasticsearch: Frequent and Long Garbage Collection

Tags: elasticsearch

My es cluster have 76 nodes, every one node have 128gb heap, 2000 shards, every one shard less than 30gb. I found the gc is frequent and long time. This occurred to one node "stop the wold", but after restart this node, another one node will got the same problem.

[image]

From the log, gc old take 5.4mins and memory 125.6gb -> 118.6gb .
Why and how to solve it ? plz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you're giving too much heap to each node. You're in the "too large" situation depicted [in this blog article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-heap-of-trouble) and you're running into stop of the world GC situations.

It is recommended that you never give more than 30.5GB-ish of heap to each node. If you have more memory available, that's fine, Lucene will use it to map segment files directly into memory (i.e. Lucene doesn't use the Java heap for that).

The solution to that is to lower the heap of each node to 30.5GB as described in the article I've linked to and restart each node.

Comment: But why restart one error node , another one will error ?

Comment: All your nodes need to have the same amount of heap, so you'll need to fix them all and restart them one after another, [rolling restart style](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rolling-upgrades.html)

Comment: One node "stop the world", restart it, then it will be good status, but the another node that is good status before will "stop the world" . I think your answer can not explain that. @Val

Comment: What my answer is telling you is that all your nodes have too much heap according to the best practices. It might happen on one node now, but it WILL happen on other nodes, too, that's a certainty. You need to lower your heap size and that articles explains pretty well why.

Comment: If I set heap of each node to 30.5GB, the cluster will be very slow. @Val the reason that need 128gb heap is that the large number of segments need use more heap.

Comment: It's a chicken egg situation, you need to split your index into more smaller shards (hence smaller segments) and probably also have time-based indexes (or some other partitioning key) to prevent them from growing too big.